# Как отсортировать массив с дубликатами?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив в котором есть дубликаты ...

Как можно удалить их  ,

Я пытался сделать так :

```js
let arr = [];

arr[0] = {
  "name": "john",
  "family": "unitas"
}

arr[1] = {
  "name": "linda",
  "family": "gamilton"
}

arr[2] = {
  "name": "john",
  "family": "unitas"
}

arr[3] = {
  "name": "yuriy",
  "family": "kravcov"
}

for (item in arr) {
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = arr[item].name + " " + arr[item].family;
  document.body.append(p)

}

const newArr = arr.filter(function(item, index) {
  return arr.indexOf(item) === index;
});

console.log(newArr)
```

Но выводится всё равно тот же самый массив ...

`let nr = [...new Set(arr)];` тоже не работает

`let nr = Array.from(new Set(arr));` тоже не работает

Comment: вот тебе целая куча решений https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас в массиве - объекты, каждый из которых создан с помощью своих собственных `{ ... }`. То есть все объекты разные. `arr.indexOf(item)` ищет ссылку на объект, эта функция понятия не имеет о том, что у объекта есть свойства, значения которых равны свойствам с такими же именами в другом объекте.

```js
let arr = [{
    "name": "john",
    "family": "unitas"
  },
  {
    "name": "linda",
    "family": "gamilton"
  },
  {
    "name": "john",
    "family": "unitas"
  },
  {
    "name": "yuriy",
    "family": "kravcov"
  }];

const newArr = arr.filter(function(item, index) {
  let index1 = arr.findIndex(function(item1) {
    let sameName = item1.name == item.name;
    let sameFamily = item1.family == item.family;
    return sameName && sameFamily;
  });
  return index1 == index;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: ааа... и как их отсеять ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Сейчас.

Comment: спасибо ...надо ещё понять что происходит там

Comment: @MaximLensky Так должно быть понятнее.

Comment: да так ...понятнее ..хотя уже начал грызть и прошлый вариант ...спасибо

Comment: that's how it works! thank you so much

Comment: @MaximLensky You bet.

Answer (score 0):

Храните ваши данные в Set. Set не позволяет хранить дубликаты и при добавлении в него элемента, который уже существует он просто игнорирует его. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: я согласен - где я ошибся ? https://ibb.co/v418DSy

Comment: В Set можно добавлять разные объекты с одними и теми же ключами и  значениями

Comment: Ну если у вас будут абсолютно идентичные поля, то и хэш будет генерироться одинаковый всегда.

Comment: вы конкретно можете ответить что требуется что бы удалить дубликат ?

Comment: Просто сохраните ваш массив в Set

Comment: удалите ответ ..я показал скриншот ..это не работает

Comment: @СергейБувака откуда у Вас такая информация? Альтернативные факты? =)  https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/NWqwObp?editors=1010